# DialogFlow - Prevent multiple top level intents from triggering at same time

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I have 2 top level intents and each having followup intents. They are as follows:

```
Order tea
-- Which tea flavour
---- Amount of sugar
------ Say tea served
```

```
Order coffee
-- Which coffee flavour
--- Amount of sugar
---- Hot or cold?
------ If hot, say hot coffee, caution.
------ If cold, say cold coffee, enjoy.
```

Now in happy path, one after another intent gets triggered and I can achieve the flow using the followup intents. But I want to know how can we stop the below flow:

```
Order Tea
-- [Prompt] Which tea flavour
-- [User] Darjeeling
---- [Prompt] Amount of sugar?
---- [User] Order coffee
-- [Prompt] Which coffee flavour
```

In this flow, the coffee intent gets triggered. Is there any way to ensure that while the tea intent is being processed, until it is completed or cancelled, no other intent like coffee will get invoked or addressed. If user says something like `order coffee` while `order tea` is being processed, it would say something like, `I did not get that`.

Comment: You can add fallback intents to each sub-tree and pass context along with the text/audio input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a solution for this issue that doesn't involve a lot of extra work. Top level intents are meant to always be available for the user during the conversation, this is why you are able to trigger the `Order Coffee` intent while in the `Order Tea` flow.

As AlphaOne mentioned in the comments, one way to work around this is by adding fallback intents, but because Dialogflow understand the input, a standard fallback wouldn't work. If you want to prevent any `Order Coffee` commands to work, you have to add all those commands to the fallback intent. Depending on the amount of steps that you have, this could become very hard to maintain if you add a fallback for each step with every phrase of the `Order Coffee` intent.

The best option for this would be to add a `Ordering_Tea` context as an output context of the `Order Tea` intent, this will indicate that you are ordering tea. Then create a fallback intent that has `Ordering_Tea` as an input context. As long as the `Ordering_Tea` context is active, this fallback intent should be available. So to stop `Order Coffee` commands from triggering, you need to add all phrases that trigger the `Order Coffee` intent into the  `Ordering_Tea` fallback.

This way you have 1 fallback intent that prevents the triggering of `Order Coffee` instead of 1 fallback for each step. All you have to do is add an `Ordering_Tea` output context to each `Order Tea` step and remove it once the user has ordered their tea.

Comment: This makes sense. Also putting all the triggers commands into the fallback is lot of work. This will also need changes when new intents are added like order sandwich for example. I agree with the details and reasoning. Thank you.